# Width attribute not working

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to split this post in half into two sections, where both classes run side by side with each other - http://launique.co.uk/services-test/

But unfortunately only `.card-picture` seems to be adhering to the width: 50% attribute, yet with the class `.card-text` it's not...

Open to suggestions, thanks in advance for input.

Comment: Can you paste the code where you try to split it into two sections - only relevant parts.

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Initially just remove the padding and margin of `.card-picture`

```
.card-text { width: 50%; float: left; }

.card-picture { width: 50%; float: left; }
```

Equally adjust margin and padding for  `.card-picture` as well as width

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to change width of both elements to:

```
width: calc(50% - 140px)
```

It means that width of element will be adjusted dynamically, and will fix the problem with margins and paddings.

Comment: Cheers, worked like a charm, need to have a look into this calc function.